# Squaring rectangular image with CSS/Boostrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Let's say i have rectangular image with dimensions of 1400px(height)x700px(width). I want to square it in the way that the image would keep its original stretch and the sides would be white. **I do not want to crop the image - want it to fully fit into square.**

Do you know how it can be achieved over CSS/Bootsrap?

Comment: Is it a background image? You need to show us what you have tried, maybe you are looking for background-size:cover;

Comment: No, it's an image within another div and the upper div is expanding by irregular image sizes. I wanna have it fit into the upper div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) on your container to center your image, and then use `max-width` and `max-height` to confine the image to your container proportionally.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.square-img-container {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 10px;
}

.square-img-container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-img-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x1400.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="square-img-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1400x700.png" alt="">
</div>
```